# I have json in that there is one other json object so how to check second Json object is null

Tags: java, android, json

```
[    
    {
        "vid": "45",
        "name": "hello",
        "description": "hello",
        "help": "hello",
        "relations": "1",
        "hierarchy": "1",
        "multiple": "1",
        "required": "0",
        "tags": "1",
        "module": "taxonomy",
        "weight": "7",
        "nodes": {
            "hidrupal": "hidrupal",
            "page": "page",
            "recipee": "recipee",
            "story": "story"
        },
        "uri": "http://andrd.yarrait.com/drupal6/android/vocabulary/45"
    },
    {
        "vid": "48",
        "name": "sample",
        "description": "asldfawi iawbfuiasguda jasbf jasfujad jashbdfajsdgawidba kjascbi9wa jhasbjabcuasv askjh bw ajs bjsbjda jsawioabfscja awjdbfuwga ajcsjfgjaw ajdfajs fj agfjweu8 ajsfbjw u",
        "help": "ajfawyg ahbcoiw ygajc jawhbu bua jagbwjwcwug ua jwsajwiuhcg ha bwujagua jajdwgugd uma jau wyg j h jja hg ug auj gwj",
        "relations": "1",
        "hierarchy": "1",
        "multiple": "1",
        "required": "0",
        "tags": "1",
        "module": "taxonomy",
        "weight": "7",
        "type": null,
        "nodes": [ ],
        "uri": "http://andrd.yarrait.com/drupal6/android/vocabulary/48"
    }
]
```

I have 2 JSONArray in that, it have "node" object that sometimes have value and sometimes have null so how to check this "node" object have null value

I try in this way. Please, check it and tell me how to solved this problem  JSONArray

```
mJSONArray = new JSONArray(response);

for (int i = 0; i < mJSONArray.length(); i++) 
{
  JSONObject mJSONObject = mJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

  mArrayListName.add(mJSONObject.getString(Constant.VocabularyJsonKey.NAME));
  mArrayListvid.add(mJSONObject.getString(Constant.VocabularyJsonKey.VID));

    if(!mJSONObject.isNull(Constant.VocabularyJsonKey.CONTENT_TYPE))
    {
      JSONObject contentTypeJSONObject = mJSONObject.getJSONObject(Constant.VocabularyJsonKey.CONTENT_TYPE);
      JSONArray contentTypeJSONArray = contentTypeJSONObject.toJSONArray(contentTypeJSONObject.names());

      //for getting content types and set as comma separated string
      for (int j = 0; j < contentTypeJSONArray.length(); j++) 
      {
        if(j ==   contentTypeJSONArray.length()-1) 
           content_types = content_types.concat(contentTypeJSONArray.getString(j).toString());
        else 
          content_types = content_types.concat(contentTypeJSONArray.getString(j).toString() + ", ");
      }
    }
    mArrayListCtype.add(content_types);
}
```

error occured when i listing than because of getting node object null value. the error is 
**org.json.JSONException: Value [] at nodes of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:96) at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:573)**

Comment: Did you try? `OuterObject.innerObject === null`. In your case object[0].nodes === null

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject;jsonObject.isNull("name");

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonObject!=null
```

try this code

Answer (score 0):

Try 
  nodes.length == 0 //empty

Answer (score 0):

isn't **nodes** a JSONArray?? because you have "nodes": [ ] in the second data set.

just use this to check:

```
parentJSON.getJSONArray("nodes").length() == 0;
```

if its a JSONObject check:

```
parentJSON.getJSONObject("nodes").length() == 0;
```

the method length() on a JSONObject gives the number of NameValuePairs in the JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

I Think the type should be like this of your JSON Array

[

//it is your first object

{"category":

{"cat_id":"1","cat_title":"Advertising & Media"}},

//it is your second object

{"category":

{"cat_id":"2","cat_title":"Automotive & Marine"}}

]

and you retrieve it by following code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String outerstr  = jsonObject.getString("category");

                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(outerstr);

                    String id = json.getString("cat_id");
                    String title = json.getString("cat_title");

                    Log.i("title  ", title);                
                    Log.i("desc  ", id);

                    yourList.add( new yourClassObject(id,title));
                  }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
```